# neural network: cost is erratic

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, classification

I implemented a simple neural network for classification (one class) of images in python. Layers are simple (image_matrix, 5,1). Using relu and sigmoid for the hidden layers.
I am iterating 5000 times. At first it looks like the cost goes down gradually in a sensible way.
However, no matter how many training examples I use, or what my learning_rate is, the costs starts behaving erratically after around 3000 iterations every time...
[cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xHR8.png) (click to see image)
Can someone help me understand what's going on?
Thanks

Comment: Provide also your training and validation accuracy charts

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this... Can you let me know what kind of charts would help? Thx

Comment: do you use ML library (tensorflow or keras) or pure numpy? Can you share you code? Basically I'm asking you to *evaluate* your model during training. This will help to understand the issue.

Comment: I'm on pure numpy. The only way I can evaluate the model for  now is the cost function displayed above and the accuracy. In the mean time, I learned some interesting initializations for W and b parameters and how to normalize the input X, which really smoothens the whole thing. I will look into evaluation methods, but it looks like my model is more stable now.

Answer (score 0):

In training models, you should remember that their are multiple local minima for the its cost. Your graph shows that you're cost is moving around this local minima whilst finding your global minimum, which is the goal finding the best performance for a model.

1st -  you should probably try checking for accuracy, f1-score, or loss per iteration/epoch to check if the performance is actually improving.

2nd - do cross validation and check for same metrics above for validation

3rd - implement an early stopping function that should check if you're model is improving or not.

*note: find the best alpha that would help you find the global minimum better.

Comment: Thx. I'll try and look at those metricx as well and implement your suggestions

Comment: No prob! Goodluck!